# In Service Console Apps - how can I tell if I'm on a subtab or primary tab?

Tags: console

The value returned from sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId seems to always be a subtab value. Even though it is not opened as a SubTab.

I've tried to compare against the sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId and other functions but it doesn't look right.

Is there something that I'm missing?

This is what I was trying to do.

```
sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId( function (enclosingTabInfo) { 
   var enclosingTabId = enclosingTabInfo.id;

   sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId( function (primaryTabInfo) {
     if (enclosingTabId === primaryTabInfo.id) { 
       console.log("Is primary Tab"); 
     } else { console.log("Is SubTab");
   });
 })
```

I think I know what is happening. All Tabs have a subtab (by default even if it doesn't look like it). So if you have one primary Tab and you do a getSubtabIds() call, it will return a single subtab id still.  And that is what is being returned by the getEnclosingTabId() call.  So I guess to check if it is a subtab I'll have to check if the primary Tab has two subtabs or not.

Comment: Can you post your code? How are you accessing? Is that from console component?

Comment: you can edit your ques and put the code

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is 2 years late, but in hopes this could help someone else, here's how to determine whether you are in a subtab or primary tab.

```
function isPgOpenInSubtab(primaryTabId, enclosingTabId){
    if(primaryTabId && enclosingTabId)
        return !(enclosingTabId === primaryTabId);

    return false;
}
```

Example use:

```
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(pTabResult){
    sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(function(eTabResult){
        const pTabId = pTabResult.id;
        const eTabId = (eTabResult.success ? eTabResult.id : null);
        const isSelfOpenInSubtab = isPgOpenInSubtab(pTabId, eTabId);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getprimarytabids.htm) called `getPrimaryTabIds()` available in Console Integration Toolkit. The method detail page says "*Returns all of the IDs of open primary tabs. This method is only available in API version 26.0 or later.*"

This method is asynchronous so it returns its response in an object in a callback method. In this callback method, you can loop through the array of primary tab ids to check the if the tab id in question is a Primary Tab or SubTab.

You can write something like this:

```
function checkSubTab(tabId) {
    tabId = tabId;
    //Get the primary tab IDs
    sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(checkSubTabCallback);
}
var checkSubTabCallback = function(result) {
    var arrPriTabs = result.ids;
    if (result.error) {
        alert("Error message is " + result.error);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrPriTabs.length; i++) {
            if (arrPriTabs[i] == tabId) {
                alert("Primary Tab");
                return false;
            }
        }
        alert("Sub Tab");
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: I get the idea there.  But my issue is actually with the tabId itself.  In your example you have checkSubTab(tabId) ... that tabId is always a SubTab Id even though I feel like it should be a primaryTabId.    I think I know what is happening.

All Tabs have a subtab (by default even if it doesn't look like it).  So if you have one primary Tab and you do a getSubtabIds() call, it will return a single subtab.